# How to add a developer to my Team in Xcode

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am working on a project with another developer, the app is not on the App Store yet. We are getting Git merge conflicts because our accounts are not on the same development team. I tried adding the developer to the team in the developer portal but it only allows that for apps that are live in the store. How can we work on the same project without git conflicts?

Comment: You can add a user to your team in App Store connect.  You can either give them access to all apps (the default) or you can can create your app in App Store connect and give them access to just that one app; you don't need to actually release the app at this point.

Comment: Okay, and then they'll be able to run the app?

Comment: From your question, it sounds like the problem you are having is that you aren't both using the same bundle id and app signing settings, which is why you are getting git conflicts in the project.  If you are both in the same team then you can both use the same signing settings; You will need to provide the developer signing certificate to your partner

Comment: App Store Connect teams aren’t the same as developer teams.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an individual developer account, you can’t add others to your team. If you have a company developer account, you can add others to your team in the developer portal. Note that that’s different from App Store Connect. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account to start, and then click the Membership tab to add people IIRC. You’ll end up sending them an invitation to join your team.

Answer (score -2):

Just export you certificate and pass it to your partner. Use the same certificate will solve your problem.